# How can I install Kernel Headers 5.18.8 for Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, kernel, linux-headers

I want to install Linux-headers for Kernel Linux 5.18.8 on Ubuntu 20.04, but when I run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` but it gives an error:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-5.18.8-051808-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'linux-headers-5.18.8-051808-generic' has no installation candidate
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've installed some kernel not from Ubuntu repositories.

Ubuntu repositories have headers only for supported kernels. You can't install headers with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

for any kernel you install manually.

You need to download or build the headers corresponding the installed kernel form the same place where you got the image.